# How to insert to a specific field in MongoDB collection using Node.JS and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I insert to a specific field in MongoDB collection without updating the data in the field,

```
{ subtask: [],
  isverified: true,
  status: 'solved',
  _id: 5e33ff7e7cfc8a32d07d554c,
  task: 'no internet',
  accepter: 'user@user.in',
  tasktype: 'non technical',
  timestamp: '31-00-2020',
  __v: 0 }
```

I like to insert into subtask field. How can I do it.Expected result.

````
   subtask:[ 
      { 
         id:1,
         sub:'hai'
      },
      { 
         id:2,
         sub:'hellow'
      }
   ],
   isverified:true,
   status:'solved',
   _id:5e33ff7e7cfc8a32d07d554c,
   task:'no internet',
   accepter:'user@user.in',
   tasktype:'non technical',
   timestamp:'31-00-2020',
   __v:0
}```
````

Comment: What would be your expected result ?

Comment: { 
   subtask:[ 
      { 
         id:1,
         sub:'hai'
      },
      { 
         id:2,
         sub:'hellow'
      }
   ],
   isverified:true,
   status:'solved',
   _id:5e33ff7e7cfc8a32d07d554c,
   task:'no internet',
   accepter:'user@user.in',
   tasktype:'non technical',
   timestamp:'31-00-2020',
   __v:0
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)  or [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) (`$addToSet` won't add if the value already exists where as `$push` will do whether it exists already or not)

```
  db.Collection.update(
       { _id: 1 },// condition any
       { $addToSet: { subtask: [ { id:1, sub:'hai' } ] } }
    )
```

or

```
db.Collection.update(
           { _id: 1 },// condition any
           { $push: { subtask: [ { id:1, sub:'hai' }, ] } }
        )
```

Edit -make sure your mongoose schema should be ,`subtask:[{id:Number,sub:String}]`

Comment: how to give each one a id

Comment: its _id and its autogenerated by mongodb moreover you can update with any particular field as a condition.@AmbadyAjay Updated My answer

Comment: how can i achieve the expected result updated my question

Comment: thanks works like a charm and i dont need id as it is auto generated.

Comment: when i use an insert query it create a new collection.
i want to insert into existing field without updating the data already present.